# Can't get data from WSDL using SoapClient

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to fetch some data from GLS' Track and Trace webservice. I'm hoping to get the data on a specific order with a reference number. The exact ordernumber in this example exists, and I can get access to it from their website. But I can't using this webservice.

The .wsdl is accessible here:

> http://www.gls-group.eu/276-I-PORTAL-WEBSERVICE/services/Tracking/wsdl/Tracking.wsdl

Here's what I'm doing now:

```
$reference = array(
    'Credentials' => array('UserName' => 'hidden', 'Password' => 'secret'),
    'RefValue' => '291054'
);
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.gls-group.eu/276-I-PORTAL-WEBSERVICE/services/Tracking/wsdl/Tracking.wsdl', array('login' => 'hidden', 'password' => 'secret'));
$result = $client->GetTuDetail($reference);

return $result;
```

I've been trying all sorts of ways to get the data, but the request takes around 50 seconds, and then returns this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [ExitCode] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ErrorCode] => 998
            [ErrorDscr] => No data found
        )

    [TuNo] => 
    [NationalRef] => 
    [ConsigneeAddress] => 
    [ShipperAddress] => 
    [RequesterAddress] => 
    [DeliveryDateTime] => 
    [PickupDateTime] => 
    [Product] => 
    [TuWeight] => 0
)
```

I've pulled out every last hair on my head, what am I missing here? Thanks in advance, a million time.

Comment: the SOAP implementation I've done is in PERL, not PHP, but what helped me a lot to develop it is SOAPLite, with it you can autocreate a dummy server using the WSDL and check how the SOAPlite client and the dummy server send/receive info, then try to do the same using your code.

Comment: it also helps if you can print the SOAP body you are sending to the server to execute the `GetTuDetail` function.

Comment: @Naryl What do you mean by 'SOAP body'? I've included everything. This is all I have right now.

Comment: sorry about the late response. When you send a petition to a webserver you send a XML structure that normally includes your username, password and the other data required for the execution of the function you requested. Normally it's possible to capture and display it using a debug function. `SoapClient::getLastRequest()` should give you that info so you can check what the server is really receiving.

Answer (score 2):

```
$reference = array(
    'Credentials' => array('UserName' => 'hidden', 'Password' => 'secret'),
    'RefValue' => '18235206982'
);
$client = new SoapClient("http://www.gls-group.eu/276-I-PORTAL-WEBSERVICE/services/Tracking/wsdl/Tracking.wsdl");
$result = $client->GetTuDetail($reference);

print_r($result);
```

The "RefValue" is a valid parcel number, so you should get a correct response.